# How to enable both built-in audio output and HDMI audio output with PulseAudio?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I've been searching for this issue for days now and tried various solutions suggested, without any success.

Basically, I have a laptop with built-in audio (the output goes either to the headphone jack or to the built-in speaker) and HDMI. I'm running Debian 7.5 with KDE.

Previously, I was running ALSA only and I was able to configure Skype to ring on the HDMI, but use the headphones for the calls themselves. I'd like to achieve something similar using Pulse.

I'm not sure if Skype still separates ringing and call audio when it sends them to PulseAudio, but as the Linux version of Skype can run arbitrary scripts on events, I would be happy if I could use e.g. `aplay` to play something on the HDMI port. However, whatever I do, I always see (and can use) a single output device only.

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`aplay -L`:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
```

When I try to use the hdmi device directly, I get the following error:

```
$ aplay -D hdmi alert.wav
Playing WAVE 'alert.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1087: Channels count non available
```

In `pavucontrol`, under the Configuration tab, I see a `Profile` drop-down with the following options:

```
Analog Stereo Duplex
Analog Stereo Output
Analog Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input
Analog Stereo (HDMI) Output
Analog Stereo Input
Off
```

As far as I can tell, all of these work as (probably) expected: the ones that say HDMI will direct audio output to the HDMI port; the others to the built-in audio card. No matter which one I select, I always see a single output device only under the Output Devices tab.

I've tried adding either the built-in or the HDMI device to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` using `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0` and `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3` - these either seemed to have no effect, or made pulseaudio not display any profiles at all.

Answer (score 14):

I just managed to configure exactly this thanks to the [instructions in the ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Simultaneous_HDMI_and_analog_output) :

Set the one sink - HDMI - in pavucontrol/Configuration, and the other - analog output - you specify in `default.pa` :

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined
set-default-sink combined
```

Maybe you were missing the last two lines?

**Addendum:** This is OK to add the analog output to HDMI, but what if you want it the other way around? (I want to keep analog input, Pulse calls that "duplex"...) Unfortunately, `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3` did **not** work to add HDMI output to Pulse's "Analog Stereo Duplex" configuration. Pulse would start, but no HDMI output.

I compared the output of `pacmd list-sinks` in the two situations. When I added `device=hw:0,3`, that one would show up without ports. When HDMI output was chosen in pavucontrol, there would be ports. Looking at the output details, I came up with **device=hdmi:0**.

Choose "Analog Stereo Duplex" as your pavucontrol configuration, and add to `default.pa` :

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hdmi:0
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined
set-default-sink combined
```

Works like a charm. I keep my microphone input, and on pavucontrol/Output Devices I have all options for analog output **and** for HDMI.

Comment: What do you think about this proposal? http://askubuntu.com/a/78179/25388 - - I could not get it work, still trying to get your proposal work in Debian 8.7.

Comment: I coud not get the last proposal work. I see now two options for simultaneous output but none of them work.

Comment: This is just to play same app/source to different sinks? Or to play one app on analog and another app on HDMI? I know the last one is possible...

Comment: This worked for me after restarting pulseaudio via `killall pulseaudio`.

Answer (score 0):

PipeWire reached version 1.0 in 2023, and distros are gradually replacing PulseAudio with PipeWire. I've written a blog post about having [Multiple ports simultaneously in PipeWire](https://denilson.sa.nom.br/blog/2023-11-10/pipewire-multiple-ports). A short summary is:

1. Edit the [9999-custom.conf](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/blob/master/spa/plugins/alsa/mixer/profile-sets/9999-custom.conf) file, located under the [alsa-card-profiles](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/tree/master/spa/plugins/alsa/mixer/profile-sets) directory structure.
2. Uncomment the example in that file, and adapt it to your needs:

   ```
    [Profile output:analog-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo]
    description = Multiple ports (custom profile)
    output-mappings = analog-stereo hdmi-stereo
    input-mappings = analog-stereo
   ```
3. Restart PipeWire.
4. Depending on your distro and depending on the configuration file location, your changes may be overwritten whenever your distro updates the installed packages.

With those changes, both the HDMI output and the analog output will be available simultaneously. With that, it's easy to use a tool like [qpwgraph](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/rncbc/qpwgraph) to route applications to each of those outputs on-the-fly. It's also possible to create a [virtual device](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices) that would become the new default output device, and that would forward the audio to multiple physical devices.

PipeWire is extremely flexible, and there are many possibilities and multiple solutions. Old PulseAudio-based solutions should still continue working, but they can also be [migrated to the newer pipewire modules](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Migrate-PulseAudio#modules-1).