# HPE Zbook 15 G3 w/ Ubuntu 17.10 – no audio through analog ports

Tags: ubuntu, audio, nvidia

The Zbook 15 G3 is currently running:

- kernel: 4.13.0-38-generic
- NVidia:  384.111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1

```
lspci | grep -i nvi
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
```

I can't get any output at all through the analog ports.  I know audio does work because I get audio through a Plantranics headset with a USB dongle but the internal speakers and the headset port on the side are completely silent.

This post seemed to be closest to my issue, and it changed the behavior somewhat as I now see the NVidia hda device:

[How to enable both built-in audio output and HDMI audio output with PulseAudio?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143865/how-to-enable-both-built-in-audio-output-and-hdmi-audio-output-with-pulseaudio)

I added this to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
### Load analog device  4/19  
#https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Simultaneous_HDMI_and_analog_output
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hdmi:0
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined
set-default-sink combined
```

The only thing this changed is that in pavucontrol I can now see the NVidia HDA device but not on the 'Configuration' tab.

`aplay -l` shows the same output even after that is done and a reboot:

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Ditto for `amixer`:

`amixer -d`

```
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

Syslog shows this repeating, so something isn't right:

```
Apr 19 10:17:19 rbeldin-HP-ZBook-15-G3 pulseaudio[2492]: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
```

Oddly, if I bring up pavucontrol I can see the output levels moving even as there is no sound.   Under configuration the only device that shows up is the "Digital Stereo HDMI (Unplugged)" which is correct because I don't have an external monitor connected right now.

From the BIOS level, the only things I had to do was change the video to discrete graphics and turn off secure boot for NVidia.   It is my recollection that this briefly worked with the inbox nv driver, but I am not too sure about that.

Not sure how to proceed at this point or what data to collect.  Any ideas would be helpful.   I have full alsa-info but it is lengthy but would be willing to share if that would be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that there is an option in BIOS to enable/disable built-in audio.  For whatever reason, this was set off, so the OS wouldn't see the devices.  After enabling that and rebooting, `aplay -L` now shows a lot more:

```
$ aplay -L                                                   
default                                                                                      
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server                                   
null                                                                                         
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)                        
pulse                                                                                        
    PulseAudio Sound Server                                                                  
sysdefault:CARD=PCH                                                                          
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog                                                            
    Default Audio Device                                                                     
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0                                                                         
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog                                                            
    Front speakers                                                                           
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0                                                                    
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog                                                            
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers                                      
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0                                                                    
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog                                                            
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20724 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: Apologies about the formatting....

Comment: I just signed up, just to comment on this. Your post and findings are really helpful. I was given a laptop with no service tags and had almost no clue on what to look for until I saw your post, and realized that the audio devices may have been disabled in the BIOS.